# If I call a function inside of a SQL query, will it get evaluated on every row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a series of constant functions to make programming and reading some of my SQL queries easier. For instance,

`dbo.CONST_DogBreed(NVARCHAR(MAX))` will return an `INT` for a given dog breed. E.g., `dbo.CONST_DogBreed('Labrador')` may return `12`.

The question I have is, if I call this function with a constant in a query, will it evaluate it repeatedly or will it realize that it's a constant and only evaluate it once? So, if I were to do:

```
SELECT * FROM Dogs
WHERE [DogType] = dbo.CONST_DogBreed('Labrador')
```

Is it going to evaluate `dbo.CONST_DogBreed('Labrador')` every single time? I realize the solution here would be to declare the value that I want in a variable above, but if it's unnecessary I'd prefer not to.

I.e. having to do this at the top of each of the queries:

```
DECLARE @LabradorBreed INT = dbo.CONST_DogBreed('Labrador');
SELECT * FROM Dogs
WHERE [DogBreed] = @LabradorBreed
```

After some research while writing this question, it seems that it's likely based on whether the function is Deterministic or not. If so, how do I make sure my function is deterministic? Will it do it for me? There are a couple of sql questions that specify Deterministic and a couple of others that use things like Schema Binding. Since my const functions don't use any schema, I'd think schema binding was unnecessary.

So I guess after this research it comes down to: How do I ensure that my function is deterministic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Database Engine automatically analyzes the body of Transact-SQL
>   functions and evaluates whether the function is deterministic. For
>   example, if the function calls other functions that are
>   non-deterministic, or if the function calls extended stored
>   procedures, then the Database Engine marks the function as
>   non-deterministic. For common language runtime (CLR) functions, the
>   Database Engine relies on the author of the function to mark the
>   function as deterministic or not using the SqlFunction custom
>   attribute.

...

> you need to add WITH SCHEMABINDING to the header of a user defined function in order to
>   make it applicable for a "Deterministic" label.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187440(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It will never conclude it is deterministic unless created `with schemabinding`